# How to Connect to a device in android using WiFiP2p without discovering it

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I want to connect my tablet to my phone using **WiFi direct** in order to send some data like pictures etc from my phone to tablet.
But I do not want my phone to discover it first i.e I don't wanted to use **discoverPeers()** method of **WiFiP2pManger**.
How can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2):

In your phone, use createGroups(). This makes your phone become the groupOwner. Then call discoverPeers() in your tablet, it will find your phone without your phone calling discoverPeers().

In your phone:

```
wifiP2pManager = (WifiP2pManager) context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
channel=wifiP2pManager.initialize(context,context.getMainLooper(),null);
wifiP2pManager.createGroup(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Log.i(TAG,"Creating p2p group");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int i) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Creating group failed, error code:"+i);

        }
});
```

In your tablet, discover peers, request peers and connect peers as normal

Comment: I have provided with the code, in this way, you do not have to call discoverPeers()

Answer (score 1):

In order to establish a WiFi Direct connection **both phones should be running WiFi Direct discovery**. In other words, they will see each other when they are both scanning for WiFi direct connections at the same time. This is because the way WiFi Direct works is that when phones are scanning for WiFi Direct connections, they will negotiate with the other peers for the role of Access Point or Slave device. Hence **both need to call discoverPeers()** to become discoverable themselves and find nearby devices.

In your use case you could even  build your application **using  wifi hotspot**

Answer (score -2):

This solution doesn't work. In Android both need to be on discovery mode in order to connect.